# GCC compiler error: "redefinition...previously defined"

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction

I'm getting a lot of " redefinition of x....x previously defined here". Please what does this error means?

Answer (score 38):

You need to limit each file from being included only once.  You can do this in 2 ways.

1) At the top of your header files put:

```
#pragma once
```

Or 2) if your compiler doesn't support that, put at the top/end of your header files:

```
#ifndef _MYFILE_H_
#define _MYFILE_H_
...
#endif
```

Replace MYFILE with the name of your file, and replace ... with the contents of the header file.

Comment: I think that #pragma only works in VC++, not in gcc.  The #define trick is portable.

Comment: Wikipedia says #pragma once is supported by VC++ and gcc http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once .

Comment: #pragma works fine with gcc.. I'm using it at this very moment after I reading about it and it solved a ton of errors!

Answer (score 14):

The error means that there is a symbol that has been defined in one place and an alternate definition has been made in another place.

This can occur if in cases like:

- if you define two functions with the same name
- if there is a mismatch between a function and it's prototype
- you call a non-trivial function before it has been defined, and without a prototype

In this last case there will be a mismatch between the real function and the "implicit declaration" that the compiler assumes when it doesn't have a prototype to use.

These situations can be avoided by:

- Ensuring that function prototypes are only declared once
- Ensuring that all functions have unique names within their scope (ie. within a file if they are `static`, or unique if they are used between object files)
- Be careful if using `extern` statements in source files to declare prototypes. Better to use a prototype from the appropriate header file.
- Ensure that all functions have prototypes - either within the source file in the case of `static` functions, or in a header file if they are to be used by other object files.
- Ensure that all header files can only be included once for each source file, by using either of the constructs suggested by Mehrdad and Brian R. Bondy

Answer (score 7):

You are probably including a header file twice. Make sure your header files are surrounded by `#ifndef` statements.

http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/preprocessor/ifdef.html

Answer (score 0):

The same thing just happened to me and it was because I accidentally included the .c/.cpp file (within it) instead of the header file.

That would definitely get you a lot of that error.